# Script for importing CSV data to animate objects

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, animation

I need to animate objects by coordinates in Unity from a CSV file. I wrote a code where I take coordinates from a file. But I cannot understand in which direction to move on. Who has any thoughts?

Here it is (Unity C#):

```
public GameObject HipCenter;
public GameObject Spine;
public GameObject ShoulderCenter;
public GameObject Head;
public GameObject ShoulderLeft;
public GameObject ElbowLeft;
public GameObject WristLeft;
public GameObject HandLeft;
public GameObject ShoulderRight;
public GameObject ElbowRight;
public GameObject WristRight;
public GameObject HandRight;
public GameObject HipLeft;
public GameObject KneeLeft;
public GameObject AnkleLeft;
public GameObject FootLeft;
public GameObject HipRight;
public GameObject KneeRight;
public GameObject AnkleRight;
public GameObject FootRight;
public TextAsset csvFile;

float[][] dataArray;

void Start() => dataArray = readCSV(); 


public float [][] readCSV()
{
    
    string[] rows = csvFile.text.Split('\n');
    float[][] retArray = new float[rows.Length][];
    for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] s = rows[i].Split(',');
        for (int j = 1; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            retArray[i][j] = float.Parse(s[j]); // FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format
        }
        return retArray;
    }
    
}
```

I have a CSV file with coordinates [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJtZ2.png) I want to read this file and to animate the game objects in Unity [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwfD.png)

Comment: Can you post the value that is failing?  Add to your code for debugging Console.WriteLine(rows[i]);

Comment: hello, welcome to SO. can you explicate your problem? what exactly are you trying to archive? do you have a problem reading the file? do you have a problem with the animation, if so what problem exactly? Would be great if you were able to narrow down your question to a specific problem

Comment: You only show us a method returning `float[][]` .... what is your goal? How are these values supposed to be applied to your objects ...? How does your CSV file look like? Wouldn't you rather e.g. add an identifier column e.g. go by object name and use a dictionary?

Comment: @nka_Zz   I supplemented my question above. Yes, i have a problem reading the CSV file. Namely FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here is how you could implement it, this is super rudimentary and would fail if the CSV has any other structure. so i would advise to implement checks to make sure your program does not fail if the CSV has a different structure.

```
public class Character
{
    public float Timestamp;
    public Vector3 Hip;
    public Vector3 Spine;
    public Vector3 ShoulderCenter;
    public Vector3 Head;
    //etc etc etc
}
```

and the class where you read your CSV

```
private CultureInfo ci;
List<Character> step;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //depending on your operation system you should set the CultureInfo (just to make sure that , is read as decimal)
    ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
    step = new List<Character>();
    LoadCSV();
}

public void LoadCSV()
{
    //read in data file
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/Data.csv");
    List<string> rows = new List<string>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        rows.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    }
    reader.Close();

    //we start on line 1 because the first one is the header
    for(int i = 1; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //delimiter csv has ';'
        var column = rows[i].Split(';');
        Character tmp = new Character();
        tmp.Timestamp = float.Parse(column[0], ci);
        tmp.Hip = ParseVector3(column[1], column[2], column[3]);
        tmp.Spine = ParseVector3(column[4], column[5], column[6]);
        tmp.ShoulderCenter = ParseVector3(column[7], column[8], column[9]);
        tmp.Head = ParseVector3(column[10], column[11], column[12]);
        //etc etc etc
        step.Add(tmp);
    }
}

public Vector3 ParseVector3(string x, string y, string z)
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3();
    position.x = float.Parse(x, ci);
    position.y = float.Parse(y, ci);
    position.z = float.Parse(z, ci);

    return position;
}
```